# Processing: The function "toArray()" expects parameters like: "toArray(T[])"

Tags: java, processing

I have some code that contains this hashmap (I removed all but 5 of the pairs to simplify):

```
HashMap<String, Integer> partiesColors = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
{
  partiesColors.put("None", color(0, 0, 0, 0));
  partiesColors.put("KPÖ", color(170, 0, 0));
  partiesColors.put("PILZ", color(128, 128, 128));
  partiesColors.put("Grüne", color(81, 165, 30));
  partiesColors.put("SPÖ", color(227, 30, 45));
};
```

I am trying to extract the colors to make a single array with them all with this line:

```
color[] colorsOnly = partiesColors.values().toArray(new color[partiesColors.size()]);
```

But the Processing (3.5.4) IDE refuses to accept that, and redlines the toArray part with `The function "toArray()" expects parameters like: "toArray(T[])"` despite the orthography being identical to several resources I found online. How am I supposed to do this?

Comment: Values of the hashmap are ints not colors

Comment: @m0skit0 Replacing "color" with "Integer" removes the error, but how do I get an array of colors instead of an array of ints?

Comment: How is the code where you put the colors in the hashmap not giving you an error? It seems that's not the actual code you're using; can you post the actual code?

Comment: @m0skit0 Apart from a few lines removed in the middle of the hashmap, this is the code I'm using (though it's not in the main file, while the converter is in the void setup() of the mainfile)

Comment: Not possible since the Map is declared as `Map<String, Integer>` and you're putting `color` in it. Can you post `color` class definition?

Comment: Uhh... I'm using the builtin color class

Comment: There's no built-in `color` class. Do you mean `Color` in Android?

Comment: No, the Processing builtin color class

Answer (score 0):

You could make an ArrayList (ArrayList is more flexible, than an Array).

```
ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i<=4; i++){

colors.add(partiesColors.get(i))
}
```

Adds the first 5 values of the HashMap, which are linked to the index.

You could also try this:

```
Object[] colorArray = partiesColors.entrySet().toArray();
```

Comment: I meant a solution that fits on one line (like the .values().toArray() example I find everywhere but that doesn't work for me), not one requiring looping over all values

Comment: Does the second approach with .entryset() work?

Comment: It works, but I am trying to get an array of colors (not an array of generic objects)

Answer (score 0):

`color` is *syntatic sugar* for `int` offered by the Processing IDE.

In fact, there is no real `color` type or class; the pre-processor converts all uses of `color` to `int` when the script is compiled to Java.

Hence you can use `int` and `color` interchangeably, and so your array doesn't **need** to be of type `color`.

```
Integer[] colorsOnly = partiesColors.values().toArray(new Integer[partiesColors.size()]);
color col = colorsOnly[0];
```